# How do I remember current div height and animate next div height accordingly?

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation with 3 drop down menus (side by side) with different height due to different content.

Currently I have it working so that each drop down on hover starts from 0 and animates to its height.

I want to improve this by remembering the current height, so when the mouse hovers the next dropdown, it will only animate the height different.

Can someone please help me with this?

This is what I have so far:

```
var expandLi = $('#header .nav .wrapper > ul > li.expand');

$(expandLi).hover(function(){       
    var startHeight = 0;
    var maxHeight = $(this).find('.expandPanel').height();
    $(this).find('.expandPanel').height(startHeight);       
    $(this).find('.expandPanel').animate({'height':maxHeight});
}, function(){ 
    $(this).find('.expandPanel').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Can't you just make startHeight a global variable and keep updating it?

Comment: can you show me how i can do that?

Comment: adeneo's answer does what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get it, but could'nt you just add to the startheight ?

```
var expandLi = $('#header .nav .wrapper > ul > li.expand'), startHeight = 0;

$(expandLi).hover(function(){
    var elem = $('.expandPanel', this),
        maxHeight = elem.height();
    elem.height(startHeight).animate({'height':maxHeight}, 1000, function() {
        startHeight += maxHeight;
    });
}, function(){ 
    var elem = $('.expandPanel', this),
        maxHeight = elem.height();
    elem.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        startHeight -= maxHeight;
    });
});
```

Comment: hi adeneo, i think i know where you're getting at, but this piece of code isn't working atm.

Answer (score 0):

You can save any additional data for any html tag by using jquery "data" function. For example :

```
$('#id').data('xxx', 123456);
```

Comment: That seems useful, but how do i add each drop down's height info dynamically into the data function then use them according?